# AirDrop to implement for a app for detection

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, airdrop

Is there any documentation for AirDrop? I want to make an app that can be installed on multiple devices, and to be able to detect other devices that are running that app, I was thinking about AirDrop to do this part of detection. I would not want to use other solutions like bonjour.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the [Multipeer Connectivity Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/_index.html)

This framework allows peer-to-peer connections (similar to AirDrop) between an app installed on multiple devices and for data to be exchanged between them over the connection.

Comment: Any examples on how to use this to detect other devices? Can I use the  device simulator from xcode to test this? Thanks!

Comment: @Tim I am developing a Photo Sharing app.
I want myDeviceApp scan for all devices that have AirDrop enabled, get UUID of each device and send concurrently or synchronously a picture or video to all devices.

How can I get UUID of each device that is in range of myDeviceApp?
How can I send data programmatically to all devices?

Answer (score 2):

You can find examples on how to use the **AirDrop API** by searching for 'airdrop' in iOS Developer Library. Here is a link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thank you, but are there any other links besides that?

Comment: I would recommend my answer more than restricting yourself to the actual Airdrop APIs shown here. Using MC Framework you have much more control and are able to see users in the vicinity as you describe

Comment: some other useful links: [UIApplicationDelegate](http://tinyurl.com/maquqc6), [UIActivity Built-in Types](http://tinyurl.com/mkbn7hw), [iOS Tech Overview: Cocoa Touch](http://tinyurl.com/osbrb9m), [iOS App Programming Guide](http://tinyurl.com/p8lnlnb)